# Mastermind game in Python

Tags: python

I am a C#/.Net developer and have decided it is time to branch out and really learn Python. I started with a simple implementation of a Mastermind-esque game. Any comments about the code would be greatly appreciated. I already know the gameplay isn't perfect, but it was just a quick attempt. I also am aware that there isn't much user input checking, but again, quick attempt.

```
import random

class Game(object):
    def run(self):
        guesses = []
        game_states = []
        length = int(input("Choose length of code to break: "))
        code = [random.randint(0, 9) for i in range(length)]

        def take_guess():
            correct_guess_length = False
            while not correct_guess_length:
                guess = input("Guess a number of length {0}: ".format(length))
                if len(guess) != length:
                    print("Guesses must be a number of length {0}.".format(length))
                else:
                    correct_guess_length = True
            return guess

        def check_guess(guess):
            return all([x == y for x, y in zip(guess, code)])

        def evaluate_guess(guess):
            new_state = []
            for pos, number in enumerate(guess):
                if code[pos] == number:
                    new_state.append(str(number))
                elif number in code:
                    new_state.append("O")
                else:
                    new_state.append("X")
            game_states.append(''.join([c for c in new_state]))

        def print_game_state():
            print()
            for guess, state in zip(guesses, game_states):
                print("{0}\t{1}".format(guess, state))

        correct = False
        while not correct:
            guess = take_guess()
            guesses.append(guess)
            guess_as_ints = [int(c) for c in guess]
            if not check_guess(guess_as_ints):
                evaluate_guess(guess_as_ints)
                print_game_state()
            else:
                print("You guessed the code was {0}! Congratulations!".format(''.join([str(i) for i in code])))
                correct = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

Comment: Why would you nest the all the functions in the function run in a class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Organization

As Simon points out, you shouldn't put the list of functions inside of `run`. It doesn't make much sense. Move them out into the class.

### Use `self`

`self` in python is equivalent to `this` in C# and many other languages.

This:

```
    guesses = []
    game_states = []
    length = int(input("Choose length of code to break: "))
    code = [random.randint(0, 9) for i in range(length)]
```

Should be this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.guesses = []
    self.game_states = []
    self.code = [] # Add this later when you define length.
```

(Also, I would keep `length` as a local variable defined in `run` and then refer to `len(self.code)` instead.)

I would advise you look at [how Python classes work.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html)

You can replace `random.randint(0, 9)` with `random.randrange(10)`.

Furthermore, once you pull the functions out of `run`, things like:

```
def take_guess():
```

become:

```
def take_guess(self):
```

## Naming

```
        correct_guess_length = False
```

I expect a varaible with the name of `length` have some sort of integer (maybe real?) value. A boolean? Not often.

You don't really need this anyway!

```
            else:
                correct_guess_length = True
```

Can just be:

```
            else:
                break
```

I would probably just get rid of that too and say:

```
            else:
                return guess
```

Same thing goes for:

```
    correct = False
    while not correct:
        ...
```

You can get rid of these and use a `break` statement instead.

## `randrange`

```
    code = [random.randint(0, 9) for i in range(length)]
```

Is pretty good except, `randrange` is a little more specialized for this:

```
    code = [random.randrange(10) for _ in range(length)]
```

(Also, when you disregard a variable the convention is to use `_`, not `i`.)

## `__str__`

Since you rap everything in a game object, maybe you should give it a string representation overloading the `__str__` function, and just print out the string representation of itself. Move `print_game_state` to `__str__`.

Comment: He should replace `length` to `self.length` if he puts the other functions directly in the class. Otherwise, `run()` and `take_guess()` wouldn't use the same variable. It couldn't even run unless you define `length` in `take_guess()`

Comment: @Aemyl: I think he should replace `length` altogether with `len(self.code)`. I mention this in the comment after `length` but it gets chopped off a bit.

Comment: As far as I know, `len()` can't stand to the left of an allocation operator

Comment: And he defines `self.code` _after_ the definition of `length`

Comment: @Aemyl: You can take the length of `code`. Also, `self.code` and `length` are both never changed. `len(self.code) == length`

Comment: Ohhhh... Wait, are you're saying that because it isn't in `__init__`?

Comment: I guess he needs the variable `length` because the definition of `self.code` is depending on `length`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50180/discussion-between-dair-and-aemyl).

Comment: The part about randrange is not right, randint is only a shortcut for randrange with step=1. So you can't say that randrange is specially designed for getting random number from x to y. That is what randint is made for. randrange is something more flexable, which is not needed in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am aware of how the classes work, however I guess I'm still hung up on everything in Python being essentially public. Putting what I considered helper functions for code readability inside the function was probably because of that. Helper functions serve no purpose outside of the `run()` function, but I do understand this limits the testability of the code because of how Python does most of its testing. Public helper functions is probably something I will need to just get used to.

Comment: As for the looping constructs, I was looking for a do/while loop analogue  in Python as it's great for user input. I looked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/emulate-a-do-while-loop-in-python) and that seemed to be a good construct. A lot of people talked about `break` having interactions with `try/catch` blocks and while I didn't use any here, I would in production code.

Comment: The variable naming scheme for the booleans is also somewhat of a holdover from the idea that conditional statements should be somewhat English readable to make reading them very easy to understand. So `correct_guess_length` when read in the `while` loop can be read as while not correct guess length which is very explanatory as to what the loop condition is. I tend to use a lot of `IsX` or `HasX` booleans because it makes statements likes `if(something.IsEnabled)` read well.

Answer (score 2):

#### Your code is hard to test

- The functions are inside the `run` function making it impossible to run (no pun intended) them standalone to verify their correctness.
- They rely on the state of the class, so even after extracting them you cannot run them on their own. Instead the code that only performs logic should have an input and give an output, independent of the outside world.

#### A class?

The game is composed of many different pure functions with just a hint of state-keeping (3-4 variables in all). I would write them individually top-level.

Let me show you one example:

```
def evaluate_guess(guess, code):
    """
    >>> evaluate_guess("12345", "19543")
    '1XO4O'
    """
    new_state = []
    for pos, number in enumerate(guess):
        if code[pos] == number:
            new_state.append(str(number))
        elif number in code:
            new_state.append("O")
        else:
            new_state.append("X")
    return ''.join([c for c in new_state])
```

Now the code is very easy to test, you just trivially call the function with the 2 arguments from any place anytime and you immediately get back the result. The test is immediate to write (you can run it with `doctest`) and doubles as documentation.

#### Simplification

Now we can simplify the code and **immediately** get to see if our correction caused an obvious bug.

```
def evaluate_guess(guess, code):
    """
    >>> evaluate_guess("12345", "19543")
    '1XO4O'
    """
    return ''.join(g if g == c else ('O' if g in code else 'X') for g, c in zip(guess, code))
```

I avoided the temporary variable and unnecessary repetition of `new_state.append` boiling the code down to the essential logic. Now the reader gets the meaning behind without losing himself on details.

Answer (score 2):

i have found that if the answer contains duplicate digits the game will output that the digit is correct but in the wrong spot
eg. if the answer is 2812 and is guessed the code returns 281o and continues instead of the win message which is quite a problem.

If you replace:

```
if code[pos] == number:
```

with:

```
if number in code and code[pos] == number:
```

that should fix the problem.